# Skipping a parameter when overriding a superclass in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, super

I'm trying to figuring out how to create a subclass that skips or doesn't include an attribute that the parent class have using `__init__` and `super()` but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I tried creating a simple inheritance with the following codes:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sound, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sound = sound


        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, age, sound, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, age, sound, **kwargs)


class Lion(Animal):
    def __init__(self, age, sound, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(age, sound, **kwargs)
```

Below, I tried printing the basic attributes/information for each subclass (`Dog` and `Lion`). Their common parameters are `name`, `age` and `sound` which are all present in my `Dog` class (I also added `pet` and `breed`).

As for the `Lion` class since it doesn't need any Name (because it usually lives in the wild) I tried skipping the `name` parameter so I didn't include it in `__init__` and `super()`.

When I run the file it gets a

> TypeError: `__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'sound'.

```
dog = Dog('Lucky', 6, 'Arf! Arf!', pet=True, breed='Shih Tzu')
lion = Lion(10, 'Roar!', wild=True)
print("===Dog===")
print("Name: {}".format(dog.name))
print("Age: {}".format(dog.age))
print(dog.sound)

print("\n===Lion===")    
print("Age: {}".format(lion.age))
print(lion.sound)
```

so I tried to work around the codes and set `sound=""` in the `Animal` class.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sound="", **kwargs): # <--I added quotes
```

Didn't get the error this time but I didn't get the correct output.

```
===Dog===
Name: Lucky
Age: 6
Arf! Arf!

===Lion===
Age: Roar!
```

I want the `Lion` to have the right attributes in proper place like the `Dog` except for the name which is not required.

Is there anything I'm missing in the code?

Comment: Inheritance is an **is a** relationship. If you don't want all `Animal`s to have `name`s, don't give them a `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix would be just to pass up an empty `name`, e.g. `""` or `None`. That's because you can't just skip arguments if you made them mandatory! Like you did in the `__init__` of your `Animal`.

```
class Lion(Animal):
    def __init__(self, age, sound, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__("", age, sound, **kwargs)
```

However maybe a better fix would be to make `name` an optional parameter because an `Animal` might have a name but doesn't require a name. Always remember that classes try to abstract "real concepts":

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, age, sound, **kwargs):
        self.age = age
        self.sound = sound
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, age, sound, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(age, sound, **kwargs)


class Lion(Animal):
    def __init__(self, age, sound, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(age, sound, **kwargs)

dog = Dog(6, 'Arf! Arf!', name='Lucky', pet=True, breed='Shih Tzu')
lion = Lion(10, 'Roar!', wild=True)
print("===Dog===")
print("Name: {}".format(dog.name))
print("Age: {}".format(dog.age))
print(dog.sound)

print("\n===Lion===")    
print("Age: {}".format(lion.age))
print(lion.sound)
```

Both approaches give the correct result (as far as I can see):

```
===Dog===
Name: Lucky
Age: 6
Arf! Arf!

===Lion===
Age: 10
Roar!
```